# Is there any Oozie action to purge Oozie logs on of MapR cluster?

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator, mapr

Is there any Oozie action that can be used in workflow.xml to purge the logs generated by oozie by 2 days from the oozie job excution?

Answer (score 1):

you can use -

`log4j.appender.oozie.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${log4j.appender.oozie.File}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}`

`log4j.appender.oozie.RollingPolicy.MaxHistory=720`

Settings to define the amount of time you keep your logs. The older logs will be gzipped and after a retention period, they would be deleted.